$a+b\sqrt{2}>1, a^2-2b^2=\pm 1 (a,b\in \mathbb{Z}) \implies a+b\sqrt {2}\geq 1+\sqrt {2}$
$\textbf{Example}:$ Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2)$. We claim that $1+\sqrt 2$ is the fundamental unit of $K$. Easy to show that $N(1+\sqrt 2)=-1$ and thus a unit. Remain to show that if $v>1$ is any unit in $\mathcal{O}_K$, then $v\geq u.$
Write $v=a+b\sqrt 2$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then we have $a^2-2b^2=(a+b\sqrt 2)(a-b\sqrt 2)=\pm 1.$ If $a^2-2b^2=1$, then $0<a-b\sqrt 2<1.$ And it follows that $a,b\geq 1.$
If $a^2-2b^2=-1,$ then $-1<a-b\sqrt 2<0.$ It follows that $a,b\geq 1.$
This is an example from a note. It's not clear to me how to deduce $a,b\geq1$ in both cases, I've tried a long time, and it seems to be an elementary question, could anyone elaborate on that?
My attempt: For the case $a^2-2b^2=1$, we must have $a>1$. Write $b^2=\frac{a^2-1}{2}$ and thus $b=\pm \sqrt{\frac{a^2-1}{2}}$. $a+b\sqrt{2}=a\pm\sqrt {a^2-1}>?1+\sqrt{2}$. I don't think this is true in general. Something wrong?

To show that $a,b \ge 1$ in the case $a^2-2b^2=1$, start as you did with $\sqrt{2}b = \pm \sqrt{a^2 - 1}$. Is it possible to have $a=1$ ?  If $a \ge 2$ and you assume $\sqrt{2}b = -\sqrt{a^2 - 1}$, can you then bound the size of $v = a + b\sqrt{2}$ ?

Is $u=1+\sqrt2;$?

@J.W.Tanner Yes, I forgot to mention that.

In https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/pelleqn1.pdf see Lemmas 5.1 (and 5.2) and 7.3 (and 7.4) for integral solutions $(x,y)$ to $x^2 - dy^2 = \pm 1$ when $d$ is a positive integer that is not a square (you ask only about $d = 2$).


how to deduce $a,b\geq1$

If $v=\color{green}{a+b\sqrt2>1}$ and $(a+b\sqrt2)(a-b\sqrt2)=a^2-2b^2=1$, with $a,b\in\mathbb Z$,
it follows that $\color{brown}{a-b\sqrt2>0}$ [otherwise $(a+b\sqrt2)(a-b\sqrt2)<0$]
and $\color{orange}{a-b\sqrt2<1}$ [otherwise $(a+b\sqrt2)(a-b\sqrt2)>1]$.
Adding $\color{brown}{a-b\sqrt2>0}$ and $\color{green}{a+b\sqrt2>1}$, we get $2a>1$, which means $a\gt\frac12$ or $a\ge1$.
Adding $\color{orange}{-a+b\sqrt2>-1}$ and $\color{green}{a+b\sqrt2>1}$, we get $2b\sqrt2>0$, which means $b>0$ or $b\ge 1$.
The case $a^2-2b^2=-1$ is similar so left to the reader.
